# Facebook Graph API shows different results in me/home

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, feed

When I do a GET with my browser (already logged-in at Facebook):

> https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token={token}

the results are different than doing the same via a FB app using Facebook C# SDK.

Specifically, what the API is not returning are feeds posted by other applications.

Why can be this happening? Can't an application retrieve updates from other applications even if it has the read_stream permission?

I even requested for additional permissions:  read_stream,user_activities,friends_activities,friends_likes,user_likes,read_requests

but nothing has changed.

What I need is to get ALL and the same stories an user would see at his FB news feed.

Comment: Are you using the exact same access token for each request. There is no reason why the Facebook C# SDK would do this. All it is doing is serializing json that is returned from Facebook.

Comment: In the C# SDK you should run: dynamic result = fb.Get("me/home"); are you doing so? Or can you post your code?

Comment: I just observed something similar comparing the API call vs. the New Feed in my browser. The API call returns different entries (some extra, some are missing) than the web.

Answer (score 1):

I use

- me/feed
- me/posts
- me/statuses
- me/links

Sample for a page: http://apps.facebook.com/anotherfeed/wallfeed.php  uses the /pageid/feed

In filtering for my wall plugin.  Even with perms, if a friend has interacted with a post and is not sharing interaction the post will not show in Graph.  Technically unless you have perms from all friends, and friends of friends you can not fully emulate the wall feed.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the results are different according the geo-localisation.

If your server is hosted in another country it might be the reason why

Comment: How are you testing this? My local server (through the API) vs. home feed are displaying different content and I'm definitely not moving!

Comment: At the time I wrote the comment, yes, I tested it using different regions from AWS